# How to restrict to download attached documents (ir.attachment) in odoo10?

Tags: python, odoo

I am setting up attachments with custom module, now i need to restrict users to only upload attachments and can not download that attachments based on group?

Comment: For this you have to create group which allow and restrict users to download the attachments.

Comment: I have created groups but didn't working on it.